# Create your own data structure class or use existing implementation?

Tags: java, data-structures

So I've been going through data structure, I can create my own linkedlist class with its functions ( insert, remove, length etc ) but why should I do that when I can simply do the following

```
LinkedList<>list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Existing implementations in the Java language are highly optimized. You won't beat that with custom code. Use existing implementation. Use custom stuff if you want to *customize* something, e.g. algorithm.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create this.  Java Generics let you do something like `List<T>`, where `T` can be any type you want.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Unless you're implementing them for learning purposes (which is a good thing to do at least once), as others already told you, you should use the battle-tested, optimized implementations.

Comment: @akuzminykh I disagree: they are highly optimized *for the general case*, and thoroughly battle-tested. However, you may be able to create something better for your own use case, based on problem-specific knowledge. However, you should hold yourself to a high threshold of evidence to demonstrate that the existing implementations aren't "good enough".

Comment: @AndyTurner Man, that's why I've written *"Use custom stuff if you want to customize something"*. Of course, if you can do something better for your *specific case*, do it.

Comment: @akuzminykh so customize something if you want to customize something? That's not a particularly deep insight.

Comment: @AndyTurner Wait what? I'm saying customize something, if your customized code will be better for your specific case. Is my english this bad?

Comment: @akuzminykh you don't quite say that, you say "you won't beat that with custom code"; this implies that any customisation gives you the alternative algorithm, but cannot be as good. If you make a statement about optimization, you have to qualify it to say what it is optimized for, e.g. "you're unlikely to beat that across all of the general use cases for which the standard implementation is optimized."

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, you are right. I'll be more precise in future. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

One good justification to the question is: Spring models or Spring POJOs.

It can be troublesome to have bean of type `Map` in old Spring for example and autowire it, but if you create a class that extends `Map` or that failing type then it will work:

```
public class MyDataContainer extends Map<int, String> {
...
}
```

Another use is when you want to perform custom action on get or set, then extending Data Structure type and overriding one of its getters or setter can be useful, example:
strip value from extra spaces before setting or putting it in the `List`, `Map`, or whatever data structure you've modified.
I've actually had to do that couple times over the course of my career.

Comment: In that case I prefer to delegate rather than `extend`, e.g. because you cannot `extend Map`, but have to decide for a specific implementation. With a delegate you can leave that decision to a client.

Comment: I'm somewhat not sure, how this answers the question. Or addresses it.

Comment: @akuzminykh Actually I've not anticipated (Accepted Answer) either, I've addressed this:
> but why should I do that when I can simply do the following 

Because sometimes it is necessary to create your own data structures model.

Answer (score -1):

```
Generally, this question asked in an interview, design the functionality for LinkedList. 
If you have deep knowledge of LinkedList, then you can design the LinkedList for different languages.
Custom LinkedList implementation will check your deep understanding, how it works internally.
```